# How do I use conditionals (e.g. ternary operator) in an NSExpression?

Tags: conditional-statements, nsexpression, apple-documentation

I'm using an NSExpression to evaluate simple strings such as:

```
NSExpression(format: "1 + 1").expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Int == 2
```

Some of my strings have more complex logic, and I'd like to use a ternary operator. I tried using the traditional `?:` syntax, but I get an error:

```
NSExpression(format: "1 + 1 == 2 ? 'YES' : 'NO'").expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)
```

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Is there a way to use a ternary operator assuming the only thing I can change is the string?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I'm [not sure where the documentation lives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016141/how-do-i-find-the-entire-syntax-functions-available-in-nsexpression-nspredic), but I found some obscure references to a `TERNARY` function. If you try it out within an NSExpression, it works:

```
NSExpression(format: "TERNARY(1 + 1 == 2, 'YES', 'NO')").expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? String == "YES"
```

It looks like the format is:

```
TERNARY(<predicate>, <trueValue>, <falseValue>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on an (apparently) undocumented expression format then you can create a conditional expression using the

```
init(forConditional:trueExpression:falseExpression:)
```

constructor ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1418004-init)). Example:

```
let expr = NSExpression(forConditional: NSPredicate(format: "1 + 1 == 2"),
                        trueExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "YES"),
                        falseExpression: NSExpression(forConstantValue: "NO"))
```