# How do I find the entire syntax / functions available in NSExpression / NSPredicate?

Tags: syntax, nspredicate, nsexpression, apple-documentation

I tried looking for the ternary operator in the [NSExpression documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression), but I couldn't find anything. I ended up finding an obscure reference in a 3rd party website to a `TERNARY` function, so I [tried it out and sure enough, it worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73016120/how-do-i-use-conditionals-e-g-ternary-operator-in-an-nsexpression).

Had I not found this reference and tried the function myself, I would have believed that NSExpression simply doesn't support this function.

To prevent something like that from happening again in the future with a different function, is there any way to find out the exhaustive list of functions / operators / syntax that NSExpression (and NSPredicate) supports so that I can learn about its full functionality?

Comment: The list of expression types is here: [NSExpression.ExpressionType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/expressiontype). You can also look at the initializers of `NSExpression`.

Comment: Unbelievable that this doesn’t seem to exist! I can’t find anything from Apple on even long supported functions or even what math operators are supported!